# Navigate to root view-controller from modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have the below scenario.

Root viewcontroller - A

pushed viewcontroller - B

Presented viewcontroller - C

A -> pushed B.

B -> presented C.

How can i go back to A from C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write following inside C

```
let presenting = self.presentingViewController ?? self.navigationController?.presentingViewController
let navCtrl1 = presenting as? UINavigationController // in case you presented C using b.navigationController.present...
let navCtrl2 = presenting?.navigationController // in case you presented c using b.present...
if let navCtrl = navCtrl1 ?? navCtrl2  {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        navCtrl.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    })
}
```

---

##### UPDATE

> I would like to know if is there anyway to bypass the dismiss and direct pop to root view controller. I want to avoid showing View-controller B

```
let presenting = self.presentingViewController ?? self.navigationController?.presentingViewController
let navCtrl1 = presenting as? UINavigationController // in case you presented C using b.navigationController.present...
let navCtrl2 = presenting?.navigationController // in case you presented c using b.present...
if let navCtrl = navCtrl1 ?? navCtrl2  {
    navCtrl.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi, Appreciate it, But i would like to know if is there anyway to bypass the dismiss and direct pop to root view controller.
I want to avoid showing View-controller B

Comment: @Angel See the **UPDATE**.

Answer (score 1):

#### How?

To achieve this, you will have to pass the presenting controllers `UINavigationController` as a variable to the View controller you are `present`-ing. Let me show you how, and the result.

Pushing from `vcA` to `vcB` is fairly straight forward. One thing to note is that when you push from `vcA` to `vcB`, `vcA` will be in the Navigation stack. Having that in mind, let me move one.

First make changes to `vcC` by adding a variable to hold the `UINavigationCongroller` of the view controller that presented `vcC`, which would be `vcB`. Do as follows ( READ THE COMMENTS )

```
class ViewControllerC: UIViewController {

    // Variable that holds reference to presenting ViewController's Navigtion controller
    var presentingNavigationController: UINavigationController!

    //Some action that triggers the "Go-back-to-A"
    @objc func pressed() {
        // When the completion block is executed in dismiss,
        // This function will loop through all ViewControllers in the presenting Navigation stack to see if vcA exists
        // Since vcA was earlier pushed to the navigation stack it should exist
        // So we can use the same navigation controller to pop to vcA    
        // Set the animated property to false to make the transition instant
        dismiss(animated: false) {
            self.presentingNavigationController.viewControllers.forEach({
                if let vc = $0 as? ViewController {
                    self.presentingNavigationController.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

And in `vcB` you can add the following to `present(_:_:_:)` function

```
// function call
@objc func pressed() {
    let vc = ViewControllerC()
    // Setting the navigation controller for reference in the presented controller
    vc.presentingNavigationController = self.navigationController  
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

#### The results

[image]

Comment: Hi, Appreciate it, But i would like to know if is there anyway to bypass the dismiss and direct pop to root view controller.
I want to avoid showing View-controller B

Comment: Check the new code and example out. The VCB is a little noticeable thought. If it works cool. What i did was change the `animated` property in the `dismiss(_:)` method from `true` to `false`